# Redirecting external links to an intermediate page in c#

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the following code to identify source html and append the url for intermediate page.

```
 sourceHtml = Regex.Replace(sourceHtml,
            @"((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)","http://domain.com/out/?url=$1");
```

While this code works perfectly I face two problems,

1.It replaces the content of 'a' tag (which is same as href value) with the intermediate page link.

2.It appends the url for 'img' tags also.

Please help me to apply this regex for a href value only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace your regexp with this:

```
href\=\""((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)\""
```

It will replace only href value.

Comment: Hi can you modify my code and post here. I tried but not sure if i'm doing it right

Comment: previously i just did it on regexp tester. Here's the one worked with your case in c# `sourceHtml = Regex.Replace(sourceHtml, @"href\=""((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)""", "href=\"http://domain.com/out/?url=$1\"");`